# How to refer to unit tests not cleaning up after themselves?

Tags: unit-testing, terminology

I am looking for a concise way to refer to the phenomenon of a unit test failing to clean up one or more artifacts, which affects the behavior/outcome of subsequent tests.

Is there a standard term for this?

Comment: "poorly written"? If they can affect other tests, then they aren't unit tests, BTW. Unit tests - by definition - must not have side affects and can be run in parallel, in any order.

Comment: The term for being able to repeat an action without affecting its state is idempotent, so something that changes things preventing this could be described as non-idempotent.

Comment: The average developer will probably understand "isolated" better than "idempotent": "Your unit tests are not isolated. Fix them so that running any subset will work!"

Comment: Put simply this violates [FIRST principles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024785/tdd-first-principle). Tests should be *Independent* and *Repeatable*.

Comment: idempotent is a better term as it is more accurate.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1077421/1371040)

Answer (score 0):

Commonly the clean-up of a unit test is called the **tear-down**, which doesn't lend itself particularly well to this case but you could call them **untorn-down**.

In C# there is the concept of the `IDisposable` interface whereby the `Dispose` method is called to clean up unmanaged resources. You could appropriate this terminology and say that such tests are **undisposed**.

You could also focus on the *effect* of the lack of tear-down, which is that other tests are being affected. These tests are **dependent** or **coupled**.